# Is it possible to register multiple interceptors in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, interceptor

I'm trying to add an HTTP interceptor to an existing Angular application.

The point is, it already has an interceptor provided:

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: CustomInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }, 
    AuthGuard, AuthService, AuthenticationInterceptor],
```

As much as I know about the interception concept, they can be piped into each other. Thus I tried this:

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: CustomInterceptor, // existing interceptor
      multi: true
    }, AuthGuard, AuthService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthenticationInterceptor, // my interceptor
      multi: true
    }],
```

And things are working. But I'm not sure if I've overridden the existing interceptor or not. Is it OK to register multiple interceptors in Angular 5? Do they cancel each other out? Or do they simply work as a workstation in a pipeline and augment each other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR** Yes, providing multiple interceptors is fine and they run in order.

> But I'm not sure if I've overridden the existing interceptor or not.

By running your code and checking, you can see whether this happens or not. In any case, the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#interceptor-order) clearly states that there can be multiple interceptors as it talks about their order:

> Angular applies interceptors in the order that you provide them. If you provide interceptors A, then B, then C, requests will flow in A->B->C and responses will flow out C->B->A.

In the same documentation, a few paragraphs above, it is also explained that the `multi` option is relevant for this:

> Note the multi: true option. This required setting tells Angular that HTTP_INTERCEPTORS is a token for a multiprovider that injects an array of values, rather than a single value.

The documentation for this flag can be found [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ClassProvider#properties).